# ¿como soluciono error 3704 error definido por la aplicacion o el objeto? VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

hola estoy tratando de llamar un procedimiento almacenado que me genera una tabla temporal para vaciarla en una hoja de excel y poder guardar esos datos como un archivo de texto, utilizando el vba de excel pero al ejecutar el código me da error 3704 error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.
Me podrían ayudar , estuve leyendo en varios foros pero no encuentro solución

```
    Dim CMDStoredProc As ADODB.Command
    Dim CnnConexion As ADODB.Connection
    Dim RcsDatos As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Dim CadConexion As String 'Cadena de conexión
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim RecordsAffected As Long
    
    'Cadena de conexión
    Dim Servidor As String
    Dim Usuario As String
    Dim Contrasena As String
    Dim BaseDatos As String
    Dim query As String
    
    Servidor = "10.200.42.50"
    Usuario = "sa"
    Contrasena = "123456"
    BaseDatos = "WMSTEK_INTERFAZ"
    
    CadConexion = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & Usuario & ";Pwd=" & Contrasena & ";Initial Catalog=" & BaseDatos & ";Data Source=" & Servidor & ""
   
    Set CnnConexion = New ADODB.Connection
    Set RcsDatos = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set CMDStoredProc = New ADODB.Command
    
    'Establece comunicación con el servidor SQL Server
    Call CnnConexion.Open(CadConexion)
    
    'Enlaza el objeto y define el procedimiento almacenado a ejecutar
    CMDStoredProc.CommandType = adCmdText
    Set CMDStoredProc.ActiveConnection = CnnConexion
    
    CMDStoredProc.CommandText = "EXEC dbo.sp_IFZ_WS_CPD_CALIFORNIA"

    
    MsgBox (CMDStoredProc.CommandText)
    'Crea el parámetro del procedimiento almacenado
    Call CMDStoredProc.Parameters.Append(CMDStoredProc.CreateParameter("PV_OPCION", DataTypeEnum.adChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10))
    
    'Ejecuta de Script
    Set RcsDatos = CMDStoredProc.Execute(RecordsAffected, , ExecuteOptionEnum.adAsyncFetch)
    
    'Recorre el Recordset resultante para asignarlo a la celda en Excel
    Row = 2
    Do While Not RcsDatos.EOF
        Cells(Row, 1).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(0).Value
        Cells(Row, 2).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(1).Value
        Cells(Row, 3).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(2).Value
        Cells(Row, 4).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(3).Value
        Cells(Row, 5).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(4).Value
        Cells(Row, 6).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(5).Value
        Row = Row + 1
        RcsDatos.MoveNext
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: ¿Qué linea te genera el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no das detalles del error ni en que parte ocurre, en el código puedo notar lo siguiente:

- Estás ejecutando un Stored Procedure pero el command type lo asignas como `adCmdText` `CMDStoredProc.CommandType = adCmdText`, aunque es posible ejecutarlo de esta manera, no es lo ideal porque tendrías que pasar la lista de parámetros como un texto en el `CommandText`
  `"exec [dbo].[Modulos] @PV_OPCION = N'ValorDelParametro'"`
- Más adelante, aunque creas el parámetro, no le estás asignando el valor.

Entonces las correcciones sugeridas, en principio, son las siguientes (3 en total):

*Omitiré parte del código para mantener el foco en el área de interés*

```
...


'  Cambia el CommandType     |
'                            V
CMDStoredProc.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set CMDStoredProc.ActiveConnection = CnnConexion

'  En el CommandText coloca el nombre del Stored Procedure (sin EXEC)
'                              |
'                              V
CMDStoredProc.CommandText = "dbo.sp_IFZ_WS_CPD_CALIFORNIA"


MsgBox (CMDStoredProc.CommandText)
'Crea el parámetro del procedimiento almacenado

' en la creación del parámetro debes agregar el valor al final  .......................................................................         |
'                                                                                                                                               V
Call CMDStoredProc.Parameters.Append(CMDStoredProc.CreateParameter("PV_OPCION", DataTypeEnum.adChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10, "ValorDelParámetro"))

...
```

Comment: "ValorDelParámetro" que valor va ahi, no entiendo esa parte

Comment: Hola @YusaryGómez. De acuerdo con el código que publicaste, tu Stored Procedure tiene un parámetro llamado `PV_OPCION`. Si en realidad el parámetro existe, lo más probable es que su valor sea utilizado bien sea en un filtro o para formar parte del resultado. ¿Que valor utilizar? no lo puedo saber porque no tengo el código del Stored Procedure ni conozco el conjunto de datos.

Comment: Gracias, busque la sintaxis de CMDStoredProc.Parameters.Appen y pude arreglar el error basada en tu respuesta. dejo el link por si lo necesitan https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp